# how to split list of emails with javascript split

Tags: javascript, web, split

I am having trouble with javascript `split` method. I would like some code to 'split' up a list of emails.

```
example: test@test.comfish@fish.comnone@none.com
```

how do you split that up?

Comment: You don't. There is no way to find where to split if there is no separator between the e-mail addresses. And no, you can't rely on ".com" being a a TLD and ".comf", ".comfi", ".comfis", ".comn", ".comno", ".comnon" not being TLDs.

Comment: no can do. Not like you have listed.  There is nothing to separate between email address.  Now, if it had something like a space -- or a coma, then a simple 'split' would do it.  With the way that top level domains (.com, .net. .us, etc) are showing up, you can't hard code in a list and keep it current without a lot of work.

Comment: @Dr.Molle True, I could have suggested a better deliminator...

Comment: Are the domain name and the email name always going to be identical like your three examples? You might be able to get the string between `.` and `@`, then go that length before `@` and split on there.

Comment: As an actual example for @jcaron's argument: `foo@foo.commmm@foo.org`. It cannot be decided whether this should be `foo@foo.com mmm@foo.org` or `foo@foo.co mmmm@foo.org` as both `*.co` and `*.com` are valid TLDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of programming language, you will need to write (create) artificial intelligence which will recognize emails (since there is no pattern).

But since you are asking how to do it, I assume that you need really simple solution. In that case split text based on .com, .net, .org ...
This is easy to do, but it will generate probably a lot of invalid emails.

---

**UPDATE:** Here is code example for simple solution (please note that this will work only for all domains that end with 3 letter like: .com, .net, .org, .biz...):

```
var emails = "test@test.comfish@fish.comnone@none.com"
var emailsArray = new Array()

while (emails !== '')
{
  //ensures that dot is searched after @ symbol (so it can find this email as well: test.test@test.com)
  //adding 4 characters makes up for dot + TLD ('.com'.length === 4)
  var endOfEmail = emails.indexOf('.', emails.indexOf('@')) + 4
  var tmpEmail = emails.substring(0, endOfEmail)
  emails = emails.substring(endOfEmail)
  emailsArray.push(tmpEmail)
}

alert(emailsArray)
```

This code has downsides of course:

- It won't work for other then 3-char's TLS's
- It won't work if domain has subdomain, like test@test.test.com

But I believe that it has best time_to_do_it/percent_of_valid_emails ratio due to very very little time needed to make it.

Comment: I would like to person who gave me down-vote to elaborate what is wrong in my answer.

Comment: If there were only a handful of edge cases, I wouldn't have flagged your answer, but, as described above, your recommended method won't work for the majority of cases.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I have noted that in my answer, and I have set that as SIMPLEST solution. It doesn't mean it is best! Best would be obviously AI, but is not something that you can explain so easily.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have different domains, like `.com`, `.net` etc and can't just split on `.com`, AND assuming your domain names and recipient names are the same like in each of your three examples, you might be able to do something crazy like this:

```
var emails = "test@test.comfish@fish.comnone@none.com"

// get the string between @ and . to get the domain name
var domain = emails.substring(emails.lastIndexOf("@")+1,emails.lastIndexOf("."));

// split the string on the index before "domain@"
var last_email = split_on(emails, emails.indexOf( domain + "@" ) );

function split_on(value, index) {
    return value.substring(0, index) + "," + value.substring(index);
}

// this gives the first emails together and splits "none@none.com" 
// I'd loop through repeating this sort of process but moving in the 
// index of the length of the email, so that you split the inner emails too

alert(last_email); 

>>> test@test.comfish@fish.com, none@none.com
```

Comment: I believe that he putted same name and domain just as example. I doubt that he have emails gmail@gmail.com, yahoo@yahoo.com, etc.